# Different log level for same class

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I hope you can help me with one problem.
I have project with several modules, each modules have `log.txt` file with log4j properties. After deploying, this files merge into one file it is `log4j.properties`. 
If i erase `log.txt` file  for specific module and deploy, that this properties that loceted in  `log.txt` will remain on server.
I want to disable logers for one package. 
For example if i have `log4j.logger.сom.my.class=trace, append`
and then i add `log4j.logger.сom.my.class=off` in the same file.Will it disabled log for `сom.my.class?` Or maybe exist another way to solve this?